# Handling simultaneous reservation requests in restaurant scenario

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a REST API project for a restaurant reservation system with Spring boot and HSQLDB using Spring data JPA. The scenario is users can call booking service to book a table at a particular time. Only one booking must be allowed at a given time slot.

My question is how do i handle the scenario where the REST API is called simultaneously by 2 or more different users to book the same table at the same time.

I searched through this and found optimistic locking can be used for this but i am not sure how it would help in the scenario unless I make any updates to Restaurant Table record.

Below is my project structure.

Booking DAO

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String bookingId;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime bookingStart;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime bookingEnd;
    @OneToOne
    private RestaurantTable table;
    private String customerName;

    ..Setter/Getter
}
```

Restaurant DAO

```
@Entity
public class RestaurantTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Integer tableId;
    private Integer capacity;
    private String description;

    //Setter/Getter
}
```

Booking Create service.

```
@Service
public class BookingService{

    @Transactional
    public Booking addBooking(final BookingDTO bookingRequest) {
        LOG.debug("Creating new booking for request: {}", bookingRequest);
        validateBookingData(bookingRequest);
        return bookingCreateService.createBooking(bookingRequest);
    }
}

@Service
public class BookingCreateService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TableRepository tableRepository;

    public Booking createBooking(final BookingDTO bookingRequest) {
        Booking booking = null;
        final LocalDateTime bookingStart = bookingRequest.getBookingTime();
        final LocalDateTime bookingEnd = bookingRequest.getBookingTime().plusHours(1);
        RestaurantTable table = tableRepository
                .findAvailableTableWithAdequateSeatingCapacity(bookingStart, bookingEnd, bookingRequest.getCustomers())
                .stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (table != null) {
            booking = saveBooking(table, bookingStart, bookingEnd, bookingRequest.getCustomerName());
        } else {
            throwErrorWithRecomemdedTime(bookingRequest.getCustomers(), bookingStart);
        }
        return booking;
    }

    private Booking saveBooking(final RestaurantTable table, final LocalDateTime bookingStart,
            final LocalDateTime bookingEnd, final String customerName) {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        booking.setBookingStart(bookingStart);
        booking.setBookingEnd(bookingEnd);
        booking.setTable(table);
        booking.setBookingId(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(7));
        booking.setCustomerName(customerName);
        return bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }

    private void throwErrorWithRecomemdedTime(final Integer customerCount, final LocalDateTime bookingStart) {
        Booking closestBookingWithFreeSlot = bookingRepository.findClosestBookingToInputTime(bookingStart);
        StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();
        errorMsg.append("Table not available for capacity: ").append(customerCount).append(".");
        if (closestBookingWithFreeSlot != null) {
            errorMsg.append(" Table available after " + closestBookingWithFreeSlot.getBookingEnd() + ".");
        }
        throw new DataValidationException(errorMsg.toString());
    }
}
```

If i hold the `BookingService` from completion using `Thread.sleep` and create another requets for booking same table, it would create two bookings for same table with same time. How can I avoid this? Should I make this synchronized? Will synchronised cause performance issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a unique constraint on the database table which includes the day, table and time slot you should get an error on one of the two as long as you are using transactions.
You can catch the error and return a message to the client that the time is no longer available.

Comment: I forgot about handling it this way. Got my head spinning around only synchronization. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the optimistic locking using the @Version annotation couldn't help here. the @Version is used as following

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Version
  Long version;

  private String bookingId;
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
  private LocalDateTime bookingStart;
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
  private LocalDateTime bookingEnd;
  @OneToOne
  private RestaurantTable table;
  private String customerName;

  ..Setter/Getter
}
```

so after using @Version you cannot ever update a booking with the same version which ensures that no two booking is being updated at the same time. but that is not the case cause you are just creating a new booking, so I think @Transactional is enough for a single threaded application as you are locking the whole process until the reservation is completed